# How do I save attachment from Outlook using C#?

Tags: c#

New to C# and trying to convert from Python. I have written code in Python which can go through my emails and save attachments for certain mails. Attempting to do this in C# now but running into some issues.

My first stab was to Add Reference and then tick the MS Outlook 16.0 Object library and then run the below:

```
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace SaveEmail
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();              
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception : {e}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But even this simple init fails:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

I did some digging and it seems that the Outlook 16.0 reference actually refers to OFFICE 2019. But within our company, we are running OFFICE 365.

How do I browse my maibox and save attachments on specific emails, given that I am using desktop version of Outlook (365)?

Comment: Do you really want to do this on the client? Exchange 365 exposes a rich API which allows you to do these operations, against your mailbox on the server

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange

Comment: Hi Matt  

Thanks, I will look into the EWS solution to see if I can implement it.  The intention is for this code to be usable by others as well.  So each day, a different person in the team will run the code and it will pull and save attachments from their mailbox.

Comment: Had a look at the code samples here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-client-applications

But the stumbling block is the password.  I do not want the users to have to input.

For reference, the solution I coded in Python made use of win32com.client and allowed me to access the Outlook instance without any username or password

Answer (score 1):

Two steps which solved my issue :

Firstly, I had to create a new .NET FRAMEWORK project (as opposed to CORE)

Secondly, the code below was used to get me going :

```
        Outlook.Application outlookApp = null;
        // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
        {
            // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
            outlookApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
        }
        else
        {
            // If not, create a new instance of Outlook and sign in to the default profile.
            outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            nameSpace = null;
        }
```